# Circle geometry: length of triangle lines

Tags: geometry

[image]

If you know only $a, R, $ and $\theta$, can you find $d$? If so, how? Please explain!

I ran across this problem (not literally) while trying to solve another post on Math Exchange and after scratching my head for a few minutes, I decided to see if anyone else might know.

NOTE: It is **not** a duplicate. This is a small part of the other problem that I found unsolvable. Even a few Google searches yielded naught!

Comment: The image doesn't seem to have come through, so it's hard to tell what the various symbols mean. Perhaps a link to the other question would help.

Comment: a line  under angle $\theta$ from the outside point will cut the circle in two points.So there are two solutions for the length from outside to circle. To find it, apply cosine theorem with angle $\theta$. Get quadratic in the distance, find the short one, then use the sine theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

$$\frac{\sin \theta}R=\frac{\sin \alpha}{R+a}$$

from which we can find $\alpha$.

Comment: Twas the push I needed! Find the angle, do some subtraction, and apply the Law again! Excellent!

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Well Done, You are welcome! Bye